# Install4j: Adding xml without duplicates

Tags: java, install4j

We are adding various xml fragments to an existing XML file. What we need is a way to conditionally add xml based on if there is an existing entry present. To check if the entry exists we would need to verify an attribute or an elements value to ensure it's unique.

Is there a way to do this using the 'Insert XML fragment into XML files' action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Count nodes in XML file" action for a certain XPath expression with the "Variable name" property set to "countXPath" and then set the "Condition expression" of the "Insert XML fragment into XML files" action to

```
(Integer)context.getVariable("countXPath") == 0
```